# Best choice to store image is as bytes or as files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to store image in mongodb using multer in node.js. Now there are 2 ways to save image: in temporary location on server or in database itself.

Uploading images in DB takes much more time compared to just save on server and later pointing to same temp location.

However, i feel its not a good idea if ever that temp folder gets deleted or corrupt for whatsoever reason, so i thought of going with DB storage idea.

But still i would like to know which idea is better ? files : DB

Here a bit of code that i wrote for this purpose

```
const imageUpload = multer({
    dest: './uploads/'
})


router.post('/', logger.logger, imageUpload.single('productImage'), controller.postAProduct);

exports.postAProduct = (req, res, next) => {
    const product = new Product({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        // productImage: req.file.path
    });
    product.productImage.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    product.productImage.contentType = 'image/png';

    product.save()
        .then(response => {
            res.status(201).json({
                response
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error
            })
        })
};
```

Answer (score 3):

this kind of question is tricky. Usually takes answers based on opinions. Bet here we go. You may think DB is the way to go, but files on a storage is the better solution. That's the purpose of them... store files. Usually what you'll see is the usage of [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/s3/) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/). Both have different kind of storage and prices.. 
Do not use temp drive

Answer (score 0):

Uploading as a binary is not a good practice.

Because,

1 - This practice is increase the size of payloads
2 - It will take much more time

Also, Uploading to server as a temp file is not a good practice unless is not your localhost.

Because, the most of servers will not allow that because of security vulnerabilities.

So, best practice is storing files on Storage Services. You can store your files in storage services(You can find them on Google) then you can save the link to database after uploaded.